# Just infinite group

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups, infinite-groups

A group is said to be **just infinite** if it is infinite and every proper quotient is finite.
In this paper  http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.3160210604/pdf I read that infinite dihedral group $D_\infty$ is just infinite and its proper quotients are dihedral groups of type $D_{2n}$.

Why is this?

I ask also if is there a name for the dual notion: a group infinite with every not trivial (normal?) subgroup finite.
For exemple $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ and Tarsky group have this property; are there any other interesting examples?

Comment: I do not understand your dual notion: Do you mean that every subgroup of $G$ other than $G$ itself is finite? I do not think there is a name for this class. A group is called *locally finite* if every finitely generated subgroup is finite.

Comment: You probably mean "proper" rather than "nontrivial" in your dual question. Obviously the trivial subgroup is finite.

Comment: Dual question: I seem to remember some other terminology but my google-foo is failing me. But in general, for a class $\mathcal{X}$ that is closed under subgroups, you can talk about "minimal non-$\mathcal{X}$ group". So, a minimal non-ableian group is an abelian group all of whose proper subgroups are abelian; and you want a minimal non-finite group.

Comment: A group with every proper subgroup finite is called quasi-finite. The only infinitely generated ones are Prüfer groups (they're abelian). There's a large variety of finitely generated ones, including of unbounded exponent (which are actually easier to construct, although less known, that prime exponent ones).

Answer (score 5):

The infinite dihedral group acts faithfully on the line $\mathbb{R}$ by reflections and translations. Since the line is a tree, and for any group acting on a tree, any finite order element fixes a point, we can conclude that all finite order elements of $D_\infty$ are either trivial, or reflections. Now suppose a subgroup contains two non-trivial finite order elements, these must be distinct reflections, and hence generate a subgroup isomorphic to $D_\infty$. On the other hand, suppose that a subgroup contains no non-trivial finite order elements, then it consists of just translations, and is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Putting all this together, a complete list of subgroup isomorphism types for $D_\infty$ is $$\{1\},\;\mathbb{Z}_2,\;\mathbb{Z},\;\textrm{and}\;D_\infty.$$ You can check that the normal closure of any copy of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in $D_\infty$ is a copy of $D_\infty$ of index 2, and all other non-trivial subgroups have finite index, so their normal closures do too.

I don't know off the top of my head an answer to your second question, sorry.